# Server side rendering issue for some pages only

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular12

The routing part didn't work on SSR by typing directly in the browser the path or click on a tag to open a new link. By example:
The first entry route is: user, inside user click to change the route to products works normally. From products go to products/:id works perfectly. But if I type in directly in the address bar the url by example: localhost:4200/products/1 it will never find out where is the route and turn out 504 error Gateway time out.

Comment: Show us the code, how have you tried to get url when user arrives to `localhost:4200/products/1` directly. Why will it never find it?

Comment: Sorry I can't share my code but Actually I am getting this issue only in SSR or universal ,all the pages are working fine but when I reload the page products/:I'd the url request is stuck in pending state and after few minutes I get 504 error

Comment: Sorry, can't help you then. Were just blindly guessing whiteout any code. But sounds like user is losing some sort of authentication on refresh.